# autoload with namespaces/submodules

Tags: ruby, autoload

I'm using modules as namespaces in ruby. How would I go about autoloading...something like `autoload :"App::ModuleA", 'app/module_a` that doesn't throw a "must be constant name" error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass a symbol to `autoload` (probably a typo in your question), and call it on the parent of the constant, like:

```
App.autoload :ModuleA, "app/module_a"
```

Note that this works for nested levels too. Say that in `app/module_a` you have:

```
module App::ModuleA
  autoload :Inner, "path/to/inner"
end
```

When Ruby encounters `App::ModuleA::Inner`, it will first attempt to access `ModuleA`, succeed by autoloading it, and only then attempt `Inner`, which succeeds also because it now knows where to autoload it.

Comment: I understand that. But I don't want to initialize on calling any Constant ModuleA, I want to call it when someone says `include App::ModuleA`

Comment: Indeed, which is why you want to call `App.autoload`, not just `autoload`. Try it out, it'll work as you want.

Comment: how does this work with a module which contains two nested classes?